# How should I respond to questions asking for specific help?

Tags: discussion, moderation, editing, close-reasons, questions

I'm talking about questions of the form "what should I do?" or "is what I'm doing haram/halal?"

For example (Apologies, I really didn't want to point out specific questions, but I feel like doing so makes my question clearer):

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23181/working-with-aon

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23162/solving-conflict-between-my-mother-and-husband

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23171/cab-i-read-surah-al-kahf-the-cave-on-thursday-night

[Hit someone's car by accident](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23163/hit-someones-car-by-accident)

[Am I divorced in sunni islamic laws](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23136/am-i-divorced-in-sunni-islamic-laws)

I'm still a bit new to Islam SE, so I would appreciate some insight. I feel like these questions are more suited for an advice column, rather then a SE site. Am I wrong to feel this way? I do think that some of them can be edited so it seems more a question about Islam and comes off less as someone simply googling for advice, asking a question on this website, and then leaving for good. Should I try to edit them? Flag them? Or am I just making a big deal out of little things?

I'm sorry if this sounds harsh. It's just that Islam SE is disappointing compared to the other SE sites, and it's been in beta for a very long time. I'm open to be proved wrong though.

Answer (score 3):

Not many users understand the rules of this site in the beginning. So, the old users usually leave comments teaching them the rules to [ask a good question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Many new users are beginners even in Islam that they don't know how to tackle a problem and instead of searching whether something is Halal or Haram, they directly put forth their situation(case) for us to solve(like a  Judge) based on Islamic rulings. Yes, as you've found a good point, I feel it would've been good if there had been a tag called 'advice'. But if people start asking just advices, this would no longer remain a QA site as you said.

#### Yes, you can definitely take your valuable time to edit the questions appropriately(and get those edits approved by a moderator) to make questions seeking advices seem more like a good question(a one this site deserves).

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: Yeah, I agree your response. particularly regarding the significant sentence which you mentioned "Not many users understand the rules of this site in the beginning. " / Meanwhile leaving comment would be counted as a beneficial act as well as you mentioned.